# Using an object from another method

Tags: c#, object, methods

My program goes like this:
I have a public "main method" of the class, which got a data table with values.
I want that when the user will press a specific button, I will calculate something in the event of the button with the data table from the "main method" of the class (public classname()).
There is anyway to do that?

Comment: Absolutely! However you'll have to be a bit more forthcoming on the information.  What you provided makes it very hard to understand what you need.

Comment: It sounds like you could benefit from reading through some basic c# tutorials or a beginning book on c#.

Comment: +1 because you are new, welcome to stack overflow. Ofir, if you are building a windows application, Windows Forms or WPF, it is very unlikely you should load your data in the application's main method. I think you should read a bit more about windows application in C#, usually you load the data only when is needed and pass it from method to method as parameter or class field / property.

Comment: You guys talk about the properites and get\set stuffs?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick example:

```
using System.Data;
...
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{


    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        DataTable dt;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dt = new DataTable();
            //load your table here
            ...
        }
        // Create an event (maybe via the designer) for button click...
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //you can reference the datatable here, for example tell how many rows it has
            MessageBox.Show(dt.Rows.Count.ToString());
            ...
        }
```

Comment: thanks, I may use it if no one else will have another option :)